# Laravel middleware to format keys of response array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a Laravel API and don't like the variable formatting with the underscores (Angular frontend). So I thought I build a middleware that renames all the json keys with an underscore, by removing them and capitalising the following letter.

I've built a recursive function which should do the renaming. But I am having problems with the response object and/or the data array. And I am pretty sure there is a much cleaner way I don't know about?!

Here is my middleware so far:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ProcessOutgoingJsonMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an outgoing response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (is_array($response->getData()))
        {
            // Fetch json data
            $json_array = $this->rename_keys($response->getData());

            // Create changed response
            $response->setData($json_array);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    public function rename_keys($array) {
        $newArray = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $key = str_replace('_','',ucwords($key,'_'));
            if(is_array($value)) $value = $this->rename_keys($value);
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $newArray;
    }
}
```

I don't even get an error. It just doesn't work. Did I use the wrong method of the JsonResponse class (https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html)? Or is there a problem with my recursive function?

Thanks for your help in advance. :)

Comment: Just so you know: the format you're looking for is called `camel case`, and Laravel has already created a helper method to convert strings to it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-camel-case

Comment: Actually it looks like you're doing studly case (all initial letters of word capitalized), in which case it's also available: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-studly-case

Comment: JsonResponse::getData returns `mixed` type.  Could it be it's not actually an array?

Comment: @danronmoon: It's an array:
`[2019-10-21 17:44:22] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => 1,
     'name' => 'Testname',
     'created_at' => '2019-10-03 12:45:49',
  ),
)`

Comment: OK, and you've registered the middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php?

Comment: Yes... I checked it by logging.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking into formatting the OUTPUT of your app, the best way is to use Macros: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#response-macros or Response resources https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-responses

From the docs: *Middlewares provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests **entering** your application.*

But if you really wanna do it using middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($response->getOriginalContent()->getData() AS $key => $value) {
      //handle replacing of response here        
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't quite understand what you mean by "Handle an outgoing response." on your docbloc but if you're looking into filtering the incoming JSON POST request try the method below.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $replaced = [];
    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        $replaced[studly_case($key)] = $value; //Arr::studly() for Laravel 6.x
    }

    $request->replace($replaced);

    return $next($request);
}
```

This should rename all request into `StudlyCase`.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the answer of AnsellC I solved it by using Response Macros (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#response-macros). My solution looks as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ApiResponseMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Arr::macro('renameKeysCamel', function($array){
            $newArray = array();
            foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                if(is_string($key)) $key = Str::camel($key);
                if(is_array($value)) $value = static::renameKeysCamel($value);
                $newArray[$key] = $value;
            }
            return $newArray;
        });

        // API Response macros
        Response::macro('success', function ($data, $message = '') {

            // If collection change it to associative array
            if($data instanceof Arrayable) $data = $data->toArray();
            if(is_object($data)) $data = (array) $data;

            // Change to camelCase key names
            if(is_array($data)) $data = Arr::renameKeysCamel($data);

            return Response::json([
              'success'  => true,
              'message' => $message,
              'data' => $data,
            ]);
        });

        Response::macro('error', function ($message, $error_code = null, $status = 400) {
            return Response::json([
              'success'  => false,
              'errorCode' => $error_code,
              'message' => $message,
            ], $status);
        });
    }    
}
```

It registers two macros for the REST API responses: `success($data, $message)` and `error($message, $error_code, $status)`. There is a third macro extending `Illuminate\Support\Arr` to recursive changing the keys to camelCase `renameKeysCamel`.

As completion here is the code to handle incoming request by a middleware and change the JSON keys to snake_case:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProcessIncomingJsonMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request and change json data keys to snake_case.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->isJson())
        {
            // Fetch json data
            $json_array = $this->renameKeysSnake($request->json()->all());
            // Create changed response
            $request->json()->replace($json_array);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function renameKeysSnake($array) {
        $newArray = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(is_string($key)) $key = Str::snake($key);
            if(is_array($value)) $value = $this->renameKeysSnake($value);

            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $newArray;
    }
}
```